# Which option is better for faster file transfer?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, file-transfer

If I have a dual band wireless router and two computer connected to it (wirelessly), and I need to transfer a big file between the computers, would it be faster for both computers to use the same band or different band? Let's assume for simplicity that there are no other devices connected to the router for the period of the file transfer.

I'm asking instead of testing myself that it requires some arrangements to perform the transfer so it would be nice to know before hand what option is the best. If could not get an answer I will have try and find out. Or get an external HDD or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first refer you to this [link](http://www.speedguide.net/faq_in_q.php?qid=340).

Basically speaking, if your device is a simultaneous dual-band router, the potential bandwidth could have been doubled. However, this is subject to other limitations:

- Compatibility. Your device may not work properly in 5GHz channel.
- 802.11 version. I'm not sure if both band will offer equal transmission rate. Say if the 2.4GHz channel can give 300Mbps rate while the other has only 54Mbps, the throughput boost may not be as significant.
- Router implementation. The router will need to hand over data from one interface to another if operating in two bands, of which the efficiency is unknown.

Basically, I'll expect higher throughput when using two bands, but the gain would generally be less than 2.

Comment: Thank you for this. As far as compatibility goes, both computers can see the both bands networks that the router produces. That's just to clarify. The rest of the answer also makes sense and helpful.